# How to get all available Azure VMs' core and ram details

Tags: azure, azureportal, ratecard-api

How can we find the core and ram details of Azure VM SKUs programmatically?

I have used the Ratecard api to get a list of available SKUs with their availability region and pay-as-you-go prices but couldn't find their exact specifications.

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackOverflow. As you can read in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) your question is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new here to get you started on writing some code you can come back with to ask a specific question about a code problem,

Have a look at the guide that was done by *The Scripting Guys*:

[Retrieve Azure Resource Manager Virtual Machine Properties by Using PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/05/31/retrieve-azure-resource-manager-virtual-machine-properties-by-using-powershell-part-2/)